# How to change cursor to custom after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change my cursor after clicking on button (on whole page), and save it somewhere maybe in localstorage, beacause after refreshing or changing the page i still want to have this custom cursor.

I want to apply custom cursor with URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read about limitations and rules about cursor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl)

```
<button onClick="changeCursor()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
  function changeCursor() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.cursor = "url('my-cursor.png'), auto";
    localStorage.setItem('customCursor', 'true');
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('customCursor') == 'true') {
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.cursor = "url('my-cursor.png'), auto";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to do this with custom url cursor. When i replace "help" with "url('cursor3.png'), auto;" it doesnt work :(

Comment: is your cursor3.png working as a cursor if you set it directly in css ?

Comment: Yes,  it is ....

Comment: well, it should! try removing the ; at the end

Comment: Still not working, i got 404 not found

Comment: so the problem is with the url..  check url('/cursor3.png'), auto or url('./cursor3.png'), auto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224286/discussion-between-amin-setayeshfar-and-j-maria).